# is Flash plugin in WebView on Mac different from Flash plugin in Safari? does it have regular Flash garbage collection?

Tags: macos, flash, cocoa, webkit, webview

an answer here [opening swf files using WebKit framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688699/opening-swf-files-using-webkit-framework) says the following about running SWF movies inside WebView inside Cocoa application: "because the Flash plug-in is not garbage-collection supported, the plug-in won't work if your application uses garbage collection".

Meanwhile, an answer here [Flash AS3 animation in Mac vs Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050014/flash-as3-animation-in-mac-vs-windows) discusses Flash garbage collection on Mac (likely in Safari) and says that it sucks but it does exist.

So is the first claim about no garbage collection in WebView false or is the WebView plugin distinct from Safari plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two types of garbage collection. The first answer you link to is talking about Objective-C garbage collection. This will only be enabled if you specifically compile your app as a garbage-collected app. This is not the default and Apple recommends you now use ARC instead of garbage collection.

The Flash plug-in is *not* compiled using Objective-C garbage collection, so it won't load in an app that uses Objective-C garbage collection because garbage-collected apps link against a different runtime.

Your second link is discussing garbage collection *in the SWF runtime of the Flash plug-in itself*. This is to do with objects in SWFs being garbage collected by the plug-in environment while a Flash movie is executing. This has nothing to do with loading the plug-in into a Cocoa app.

The Flash plug-in is the same whether it's loaded into Safari or a `WebView`.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer. BTW do you by any chances have any thoughts about my other Flash and Mac related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643427/what-are-pros-cons-between-adobe-air-executable-and-a-native-app-to-playing-equi ?